# Java script pass function with arguments to another function

Tags: javascript, function, parameter-passing

Hi I would like to pass function to another but the without affecting middle function in my code

`checkUserAndStart(startFunction)` - this function I want to reuse in many places (to check logged user - if is logged start function but not always with parameters)

```
  function startInTorry(email,displayName){         
      $('#footer-email').html(email);
      $('#InTorryUserName').html(displayName);        
  }

  function checkUserAndStart(startFunction) {
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
        if (user) {
          //user.email,user.displayName is from here
          startFunction();
        } else {
          window.location = 'login.html'
        }
      })
    }

  $(document).ready(function () {       
    checkUserAndStart(function(){startInTorry(user.email,user.displayName)})
  })
```

Comment: whats problem you are getting here ?

Comment: it doesnt display email in $('#footer-email').html(email);ReferenceError: "user is not defined"

Answer (score 1):

You *pass* the function without its arguments. Then, when you *call* it, you call it with arguments.

```
function startInTorry(email,displayName){         
      $('#footer-email').html(email);
      $('#InTorryUserName').html(displayName);        
}

function checkUserAndStart(startFunction) {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
    if (user) {
      startFunction(user.email, user.displayName);
    } else {
      window.location = 'login.html'
    }
  })
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  checkUserAndStart(startInTorry);
})
```

Comment: Hi Wiktor, The question was not to affect the middle function. I want to reuse it in many places sometimes without parameters. Regards